# AuthenticationProvider function authenticate not call after migration to spring security 4

Tags: spring-security, migration, spring-security4

AuthenticationProvider function authenticate not call after migration spring security 2 to spring security 4.

I am use custom provider and ldap authentication, all of my config its ok , but when I try to connect , I have an anonymousUser in my AccessDecisionVoter.vote

please see the description code here:

```
    public class RoleVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<Object> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @see AccessDecisionVoter#supports(ConfigAttribute)
     */
    public boolean supports(ConfigAttribute configAttribute) {
        if (getAttributeValue(configAttribute) != null) {
            try {
                //Integer.parseInt(configAttribute.getAttribute());
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getAttributeValue(ConfigAttribute attribute){
        if (attribute instanceof ConfigAttribute) { 
            return attribute.toString();
        } 
        return attribute.getAttribute(); 

    }

    public int vote(Authentication authentication, Object object,
            Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributeDefinition) {

                  return result;
    }
}

    @Component
    public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider  {
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger
                .getLogger(MyAuthenticationProvider.class);
        protected MessageSourceAccessor messages = SpringSecurityMessageSource
                .getAccessor();
        private LdapAuthenticator authenticator;
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
        private boolean useAuthenticationRequestCredentials = true;

        public MyAuthenticationProvider(LdapAuthenticator authenticator,
                UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
            setAuthenticator(authenticator);
            setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }

        public MyAuthenticationProvider() {

        }

    //—> not called????
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        Assert.isInstanceOf(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class,authentication,messages.getMessage(
                                        "AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.onlySupports",
                                        "Only UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken is supported"));
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken userToken = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
//my authentication     
    return return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, user
                .getAuthorities());
    }



    private LdapAuthenticator getAuthenticator() {
        return authenticator;
    }

    protected UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
        return userDetailsService;
    }

    private void setAuthenticator(LdapAuthenticator authenticator) {
        Assert.notNull(authenticator, "An LdapAuthenticator must be supplied");
        this.authenticator = authenticator;
    }

    private void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        Assert.notNull(userDetailsService,
                "An UserDetailsService must be supplied");
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class authentication) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class
                .isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }



}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
        
    <!-- Security configuration -->
             <security:http pattern="/struts/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/dojo/**" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/index.jsp" security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/pages/authentication/auth.jsp*"
        security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/authentication/authErr.action*"
        security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/authentication/auth.action*"
        security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/authentication/logout.action*"
        security="none" />
    <security:http pattern="/resources/firefox/*" security="none" />
    <!-- ************************************************************************** -->

    <security:http disable-url-rewriting="false"  auto-config="true" use-expressions="false" access-decision-manager-ref="myAccessDecisionManager">
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/pages/authentication/denied.jsp"/>
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <security:headers disabled="true"/>
        
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/struts/**" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/dojo/**" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" />
        <security:intercept-url
            pattern="/pages/authentication/auth.jsp*" />
        <security:intercept-url
            pattern="/authentication/authErr.action*" />
        <security:intercept-url
            pattern="/authentication/auth.action*" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/authentication/logout.action*" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/firefox/*" />


        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('1')" /><!-- OR access=1 -->
        <security:form-login
            login-page="/authentication/auth.action"
            always-use-default-target="false"
            default-target-url="/home/home.action"
            authentication-failure-url="/authentication/authErr.action" />

                          <security:anonymous granted-authority="99" />

 
        <security:session-management>
             <security:concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" max-sessions="1"/>
         </security:session-management>
    </security:http>

    <!-- LDAP configuration -->

    <bean id="dbLdapManager"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass"
            value="local.framework.ldap-java5.DBLdapManager" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="setDbLdapParameters" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <bean id="dbLdapParameters"
                    class="local.framework.ldap-java5.DBLdapParameters">
                    <property name="application" value="refpat" />
                    <property name="dbLdapDriver"
                        value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" />
                    <property name="dbLdapURL"
                        value="${ldap-host}" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="${ldap-host}" />
        <property name="userDn" value="cn=manager,dc=springframework,dc=org"/>
        <property name="pooled" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
        class="mypackage.security.provider.MyAuthenticationProvider">
    <!-- <security:custom-authentication-provider /> -->

        <constructor-arg>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
                <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
                <property name="userDnPatterns">
                    <list>
                        <value>${ldap-dn-pattern}</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg ref="userService" />
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider"/>
    </security:authentication-manager>  
 
    <bean id="userService"
        class="mypackage.security.MyUserDetails">
        <property name="serviceLookups" ref="serviceLookups" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="myAccessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"><!-- old:org.springframework.security.vote.UnanimousBased -->
    <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                                  <bean class="mypackage.security.vote.RoleVoter"/>

            <!-- other voter …—>
            </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="loggerListener"
        class="org.springframework.security.access.event.LoggerListener" />
</beans>
```

any solution/idea to solve my probleme ? thank a lot

Comment: which version you migrated from? Have you made any change as described in the migration guide such as [Migrating from 3.x to 4.x](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/m3to4.html)?

Comment: Yes,I made all changes to migrate spring 2.x to 4.x

Comment: @Ritesh please see the description code above.